# In a `sudo find` command, how do I make sure that `-exec` command is run as normal user?

Tags: find, sudo, su

I am trying to make the following command work in a way that `process_paths` script is not run under elevated privileges. Is there a way to do this?

```
sudo find /path/ -exec process_paths '{}' \+
```

Here `/path/` has some files that have no read permission for normal user. The script `process_paths` just needs the paths.

Comment: `... -exec sudo -u user process_paths {} \+`

Comment: @SatoKatsura sometimes this fails with `sudo: unable to execute /usr/bin/perl: Argument list too long` :/

Comment: Yes, see the note about the `SUDO_COMMAND` variable in [find . .\[^.\]\* -type f -print0 | xargs -0 sudo chmod 664; does not work](//unix.stackexchange.com/a/72822)

Comment: If you want the `-exec` commands to be invoked as your user, why are you running `find` using `sudo` in the first place?

Comment: @marcelm I think the last sentence of the question answers yours.

Comment: @YdobEmos Right! Somehow I completely missed that...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

On systems that support it (GNU and quite a few others), you could do:

```
sudo find /path/ -print0 | xargs -r0 process_paths
```

`xargs` is not run under `sudo`, so it still has the original uids/gids and also the original environment (in the larger sense), not the one modified by `sudo`.

`process_paths` stdin ends up being modified though (depending on the `xargs` implementation, it's open on `/dev/null` or shares the `pipe` from `sudo`/`find`.

To avoid that (with GNU `xargs` and shells like `ksh`, `zsh` or `bash` that support process substitution), you could do:

```
xargs -r0a <(sudo find /path/ -print0) process_paths
```

With `zsh`:

```
sudo zsh -c '
   files=(/path/**/*(D))
   USERNAME=$SUDO_USER
   autoload zargs
   zargs $files -- process_paths'
```

In `zsh`, assigning a user name to the `$USERNAME` special variable, sets the uids, gids to that of the corresponding user in the user database like `sudo -u "$SUDO_USER"` would do.

You could do:

```
 sudo sh -c '
   exec find /path/ -exec sudo -u "$SUDO_USER" process_paths {} +'
```

But because `sudo` passes a `$SUDO_COMMAND` environment variable (which contains the concatenation of the arguments with spaces) to `process_paths`, the list of files ends up being passed twice to `process_paths` which means the limit on the maximum size of args+env is likely to be reached if there's a large number of files.

With most `su` implementations, you should be able to do:

```
 sudo sh -c '
   exec find /path/ -exec su "$SUDO_USER" -c '\''
     exec "$0" "$@"'\'' process_paths {} +'
```

though as `su` doesn't have the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sudo` :

```
sudo find <directory> -exec sudo -u <normal_user> <command> {} \;
```

But as said in a comment, it can apparently fail if the {} is too long for sudo.